# Getting 'Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1)' when writing into jfloat array

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-ndk

I'm currently implementing an android function with the ndk.
I declared the function in java like

```
public static native void calculate(float[] rgb,float factor);
```

Then, I wrote the C function:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_<package>_calculate(
       JNIEnv * env,
       jobject object,
       jfloatArray rgbObject,
       jfloat factor){
   jfloat* rgb = (*env)->GetFloatArrayElements(env,rgbObject,0);
   if(rgb==NULL) return;

   rgb[0]=5; // Test, crash!

   (*env)->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(env,rgb,rgbObject,0);
   }
```

However, everytime I try to call the function with an array and some value I get the logcat message:

*A/libc(16064): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1)*

after that, the app crashes. I figured out that it always occurs when writing into the float values. Reading doesn't lead to a crash.

Do I something wrong? Isn't it possible to write the array values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution!
For some reason, the function was called with a null-value as an array. However, the rgb==NULL check didn't fired (I don't know for which reason). I fixed the problem by adding a second check before getting the values

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_<package>_calculate(
       JNIEnv * env,
       jobject object,
       jfloatArray rgbObject,
       jfloat factor){
   if(rgbObject==NULL) return; // Check if incomming array is NULL-Pointer
   jfloat* rgb = (*env)->GetFloatArrayElements(env,rgbObject,0);
   if(rgb==NULL) return;

   rgb[0]=5; // Test, crash!

   (*env)->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(env,rgb,rgbObject,0);
   }
```

Comment: Good you found the solution! :) You should set your answer as accepted so other people can find this post useful.

Comment: I know, but Stackoverflow says I should wait at least 2 days, so I can't set it right now ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I worked with the `Android NDK`, I tried to Release the memory inside the function written in `C`, and I ended up getting the `SIGSEGV` error. The trick I did was to make a function in my C code which handled the memory, and called this method directly from `Java`, after I was finished with a specific operation in Java. I called the function in C, in order to clean the memory.

Comment: I tried this, thanks for this idea. But if I comment the last line (ReleaseFloatArrayElements) I still keep getting the same 'Fatal Signal 11'. It doesn't work for me for some reason.

Comment: Hm, sounds strange. You tried to commented it out, that wouldn't be the solution. Try to make a new function something like this: `JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_releaseMemory(JNIEnv * env) { (*env)->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(env,rgb,rgbObject,0); }` Not the best answer as I dont have my code infront of me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problom as you and finally solve it.

i think   the  problom  is that  you have not init rgbObject in your java code for jni.

i just add rgbObject =new int[5] in my code  and then  it is OK.

you can also do as TSGames said.

i think my  is better.